# Submit a POST request to controller on submit TYPO3?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have a problem submitting a post request to controller. I Created a new table in database Product. I created after the model, Repository and Controller. Then I registered in the plugin the method list which gets a list of product. It works very well but in the List.html I have put a form where I want to submit something to the same controller where list is but this time is a POST method. I get action is not allowed by this plugin/module.

[ext_localconf.php]

```
 /***************
 * Custom PLugins
 */
ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'youtube_demo',
    'InventoryList',
    [
         StoreInventoryController::class => 'list',
    ],
    [StoreInventoryController::class => '',],
);
```

[StoreInventoryController]

```
<?php

namespace Contencance\YoutubeDemo\Controller;

use Contencance\YoutubeDemo\Domain\Repository\ProductRepository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;

/**
 * Class StoreInventoryController
 *
 * @package MyVendor\StoreInventory\Controller
 */
class StoreInventoryController extends ActionController
{

    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * Inject the product repository
     *
     * @param \MyVendor\StoreInventory\Domain\Repository\ProductRepository $productRepository
     */
    public function injectProductRepository(ProductRepository $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * list Action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        $products = $this->productRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('products', $products);
    }

    /**
     * store Action
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function storeAction()
    {
        var_dump("Hellow World");
        die();
    }
}
```

I tried adding the "Store" method in ext_location.php but it got called imediatly I want it only when submitting.

[List.html]

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
       <td>Product name</td>
       <td>Product description</td>
       <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <f:for each="{products}" as="product">
       <tr>
          <td align="top">{product.name}</td>
          <td align="top"><f:format.crop maxCharacters="100">{product.description}</f:format.crop></td>
          <td align="top">{product.quantity}</td>
       </tr>
    </f:for>
 </table>

 <f:form action="store" controller="StoreInventory" objectName="gamingData" method="post">
   <label>Enter</label><br>
   <f:form.textfield property="game-desc" /><br>
   <f:form.button>Submit</f:form.button>
</f:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `store` to the list of methods in your ext_localconf.php, that's correct.

But you need to add it after `list` => `list, store`.

The first entry in the list is executed by default (if no action given).

Full code:

```
ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'youtube_demo',
    'InventoryList',
    [
         StoreInventoryController::class => 'list, store',
    ],
    [StoreInventoryController::class => '',],
);
```

Comment: I still get the the same error that the store is not allowed.

Comment: ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'youtube_demo',
    'InventoryList',
    [
        StoreInventoryController::class => 'list', 'store',
    ],
    [StoreInventoryController::class => '',],
);

Comment: ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'youtube_demo',
    'InventoryList',
    [
        StoreInventoryController::class => 'list',
        StoreInventoryController::class => 'store',
    ],
    [StoreInventoryController::class => '',],
);

Comment: And if I add it like this only store gets executed without me even pressing the submitbutton.

Comment: Please stick to the official documentation. I've edited my answer with the complete code.

Comment: I tried everything except this StoreInventoryController::class => 'list, store'. Thank you so much!